# Where is the best place to store the logged user and information

Tags: c#, winforms

I've found a lot of answers for web applications, but none for winforms.

I want to store the user (id at least), the UI language in use and other general info that should last for the time a user is connected. Note: I'm developping a DLL.

So to summarize, I need to store the data while the application is open. When it's closed, all the infos can be disposed.

Possible solutions:
- Keep the information in a static class, but it's probably a bad practice.
- Create a class which has to be sent in parameter to whatever is called/instanciated in the DLL
- Create a class and find a way to make it reachable from other places in the DLL (I don't know any way to achieve that)

Note: I do not use Windows' Active Directory.
Note 2: I don't need to store sensitive data like the password

Comment: Does this need to persist between launches (i.e. if the user shuts down their machine, restarts, then relaunches you app, do you need to reload the old data)? Does this data include private information like passwords?

Comment: is this for a desktop application?

Comment: For a desktop app. And it can be cleared between launches, all the data are in the database.

Comment: @Mathieu What is wrong with a static class acting as a Cache using some form of threadsafe Key/Value collection like the ConcurrentDictionary MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx

Comment: Why do you think that a static class is a bad practice? For this kind of information it seems natural. Just initialize and then it's available everywhere in your dll. Others solutions like Singleton Patterns seems not worth the trouble

Answer (score 1):

You can save your user data in an encrypted file. You would build an xml file then use synchronous encryption to save it. (Synchronous means you have a common key to decode it, which you could put in a static class). Search synchronous xml encryption c#